# Exporting BNG coordinates from MapInfo (27700) without rounding

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo, export, csv

I have a TAB file in ESPG 27700 projection and MapInfo is rounding Y coordinate values upon export. It also occurs when viewing the table (although selecting the value shows its 'true' form)

[image]

[image]

Upon export to .csv the value stays at 53.5834. I have tried creating a character field and updating it with the MIDY value and this doesn't work either.

I am currently experimenting with generating a general text direction assigned to a polyline by first splitting it to lines and using the difference between the X and Y coordinates of the centreline of each segment and 'counting' the predominant X and Y directions (disregarding values <=5m, the 'NEG' values) with the aim of possible re-creating my steps in MapBasic:

[image]

Comment: You can use Format$(MIDX, "#.########") to get more decimals on you floating values - or use a Decimal column for your coordinates

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the Centroid(X) and Centroid(Y) in MapInfo are not the line centre point coordinates in BNG. (However to get around the rounding problem I exported the table as a DBF). Instead, I generated these in ArcGIS instead and got perfect results. I achieved my desired result by calculating differences in X and Y values between subsections and taking the predominantly occurring directions and combining them to get a general direction:

E.g. I have determined section N to be a general NW direction:

[image]

[image]